# What is 'self' inside initialize()?

Tags: ruby

say I have this:

```
class Post
  def initialize()
    vote_total = 0
  end
end
```

Obviously, this won't set an instance variable, and to do so, inside initialize this needs to be written

```
self.vote_total = 0
```

My question is...what is self inside the initialize method?

```
irb(main):022:0> class Post
irb(main):023:1> puts self
irb(main):024:1> def initialize()
irb(main):025:2> puts self
irb(main):026:2> vote_total = 0
irb(main):027:2> puts self
irb(main):028:2> end
irb(main):029:1> end
Post
=> nil
irb(main):030:0> post = Post.new
#<Post:0x007f9448d76f98>
#<Post:0x007f9448d76f98>
=> #<Post:0x007f9448d76f98>
```

I understand the difference but functional similarity between

```
@instance_variables

obj.method_instance_variables
```

but I don't understand whats going on in that vote_total line. what is self there, and what is getting vote_total defined?

Comment: Any reason you aren't setting instance variables with the standard syntax @vote_total = 0 ?

Comment: "self" is the instance, as you'd expect.

Comment: @mason If you're using `attr_accessor` or something equivalent, `vote_total = 0` is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initialize` is an instance method so `self` refers to new instance of the class. When you execute `self` outside of any method (in class body), self refers to the class itself).

OTHER NOTES:

Neither of:

```
vote_total = 0
self.vote_total = 0
```

set an instance variable 'per se'. First call creates local variable `vote_total`, second call executes method `vote_total=`. If your class has `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader` on top, then this method is defined as

```
def vote_total=(value)
  @vote_total = value
end
```

which is setting the variable. If you have none of those and you don't define it any other way (number of ways is extremely huge), then `self.vote_total = :foo` will raise `undefined method 'vote_total='` exception.

Comment: `self.vote_total = 0` is **not** the same as `vote_total = 0`! The first is a call to the `vote_total=` method, the second is the declaration of a local variable (because there no method with that name)

Comment: `vote_total = 0` is always just an assignment to a local variable, irregardless of the existence of a method with the same name.

Comment: Which ruby version do you use? You snippet does not work with ruby `2.1.1`

Comment: My apologies, @tessi. I was wrong: `self.vote_total = 0` and `vote_total = 0` are not the same if there is no method `vote_total=`. Thank you for the correction.  I will delete my earlier comments to reduce comment clutter.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Just to be clear, those two snippets are never equivalent. `vote_total = 0` will always set a local variable and `self.vote_total = 0` will always attempt to call a `vote_total=` method with an argument of 0. Whether or not the `vote_total=` method actually exists doesn't make a difference. You're probably thinking of the "getter" version — `self.vote_total` and `vote_total` — the latter of which changes meaning depending on whether there is a local variable named `vote_total`.

Comment: Thanks, Chuck. Actually, I probably mixed up `self.var/var` with `self.method/method`, for instance methods generally. I can see there is a good reason that `self.var` is always treated as a method.